# How can I authenticate Spotify in a React Native component?

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth, react-hooks, expo

I am creating a React Native mobile application for a school project and I want a user to be able to login to Spotify to be able to get information about their playback using the Spotify API.

I am developing for iOS and using Expo, so have found [this documentation from Expo](https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#spotify) to be quite helpful. Using their sample Auth Code, I was successfully able to make a very simple React app that allows the user to push a button that prompts them to login with Spotify. For my project, though, I have different components corresponding to different screens in my app. Whenever I try to move the code into a component, I get an error that I am unsure how to resolve (I am still pretty new to React and Javascript).

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest } from 'expo-auth-session';
import { View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { LoginContext } from '../LoginContext';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

// Endpoint
const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
};

const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    scopes: ['user-read-email', 'playlist-modify-public'],
    // In order to follow the "Authorization Code Flow" to fetch token after authorizationEndpoint
    // this must be set to false
    usePKCE: false,
    redirectUri: 'exp://localhost:19000/--/',
    },
    discovery
);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
    const { code } = response.params;
    }
}, [response]);


export default class Settings extends React.Component {

    render () {

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: "center", alignContent: 'center'}}>  
            <Button
            //disabled={!request}
            title="Login to Spotify"
            onPress={() => {
                //console.log("Login attempt");
                promptAsync();
                }}
            />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I get an error message that states:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and
>    fix this problem.

I looked at the link in the error message to see if I could debug myself, but I am having some trouble given that I am still pretty new to React. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useAuthRequest` and `useEffect` are what we call React hooks. They can be used in functional components only. In my opinion, you should first check the documentation of how to use hooks in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

```js
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

// Endpoint
const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
};

// This is the functional component
const Settings = () => {
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scopes: ['user-read-email', 'playlist-modify-public'],
      // In order to follow the "Authorization Code Flow" to fetch token after authorizationEndpoint
      // this must be set to false
      usePKCE: false,
      redirectUri: 'exp://localhost:19000/--/',
    }, discovery);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { code } = response.params;
      }
    }, [response]);
   
    return (
        <View>...</View>
    )
}
```